# Have all of Euler's works been translated?

Tags: mathematicians, euler, translations, 18th-century

I am interested in reading Euler's works.

The Euler Archive contains some translated works but not all of them. I am just checking here to see if anyone know a complete translation of all of Euler's works.

Preferably in HTML format.

Comment: I don't know about all of his works, but his functions get translated all the time! ... ah, such a pun-tastic question :-)

Comment: @einpoklum Sigh

Comment: Well, those works, you know... it can't be easy to fully _translate_ something of that _scale_.

Comment: @einpoklum At the time of writing that question I did not realise Euler authored so much. I nearly went blind like euler just scanning through the full enestrom index. I see now why the opera omnia exists.

Comment: I don't think so.  I seem to remember looking for his paper on the seven bridges of Koenigsberg and I can only find it in Latin.  I also noticed that the journal Euleriana accepts translations of articles with commentary if anyone is interested in translating more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not all. I don't think that they are even all published in the original language. There is an ongoing project of translating Euler's mathematical work (only mathematical)
[Euler archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org) and you can see there which works are translated.

But if you want to read Euler in English, enough of his papers are already translated in this project to keep you busy for years.

Comment: "I don't think that they are even all published in the original" . Damn. Do you know where I can find a comprehensive list of euler's works?

Comment: @Maalik The publication of Euler's works (*Opera Omnia*, comprising 81 volumes in four series) by the Swiss Euler Commission just wrapped up. This commission commenced work in 1909! From what I understand, some of Euler's correspondence was omitted, but there is work ongoing to make it accessible in digital form.

Comment: @Maalik Euler's works are cataloged and enumerated in the Eneström Index, created by the Swedish mathematician Gustav Eneström between 1910 and 1913. The Index may be seen [here](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/resources/enestrom/index.html). A scan of Eneström's original publication "Verzeichnis der Schriften Leonhard Eulers" from 1910 is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/enestrom-test/mode/2up)

Comment: Most of Euler's work (in volume) are non-mathematical. Mainly mathematical works are translated. One exception is his "Letters to a German princess" which are translated to several languages.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I just checked the enestrom list. Most of them look very mathematical and/or physical?

Comment: @Malik: If you wish you may qualify most of his work as applied mathematics; they belong to astronomy, ballistics, ship building etc., but of course he uses mathematics everywhere.

Comment: @Maalik A lot of Euler's work is in the domain of pure mathematics but uses proofs that are now considered to be non-rigorous (even if you interpret the meaning of his notation generously).  As an example, see his proof of the divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes: Euler, Leonhard (1737). "Variae observationes circa series infinitas" [Various observations concerning infinite series]. Commentarii Academiae Scientiarum Petropolitanae. 9: 160–188.

Comment: My statement that most of Euler work is not in mathematics is based on the visual inspection of this Collected works in my library: mathematics occupies about 1/3 of the total shelf space.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in reading Euler in English translation, you should take a look at Ian Bruce's excellent web site https://www.17centurymaths.com. His project involves the translation of mathematical works of the 17th and 18th century from Latin to English, and many of Euler's works are available. Bruce's work is a great contribution to the mathematics community.

Comment: thanks i have already downloaded and assembled everything ian bruce has translated. i agree, he has done an excellent job the only thing i wish he had not done was combine the latin and english together in the same document. It would have been better to separate them into two documents

Answer (score 1):

There are now 128 volumes in Euler's opera in the German central catalog of libraries [here](https://kxp.k10plus.de/DB=2.1/SET=4/TTL=16/CMD?MATCFILTER=N&MATCSET=N&ACT0=&IKT0=&TRM0=&ACT3=*&IKT3=8183&ACT=SRCHA&IKT=1016&SRT=YOP&TRM=Leonhard+Euler+opera&TRM3=).

There is no hope to get the formula digitized in the current state of mathematical OCR. There is some hope that the Chinese can do it. They have an excellent tradition and workforce in copying glyphs.

Comment: I really hope you meant 27 volumes. Anyway, are these volumes . . O compilations of various enestrom numbers by gustav ? And do they compile all of them

Comment: @Hisham If you follow the link, you'll see that it's exactly 2⁷ (= 128) volumes.

Comment: I had the same thought as @Hisham, but I somehow was of the opinion that $2^7$ was some absurdly large number, whereas $128$ seems quite reasonable...

Answer (score 1):

Some new translations (mostly into German but also into English) can be found on the website of the [Euler Kreis Mainz](https://www.agtz.mathematik.uni-mainz.de/algebraische-geometrie/van-straten/euler-kreis-mainz).